# How to map /dev/ttyUSB0 (usbserial CP210x) to a COM port in wine?

Tags: serial-port, wine

I'm running a Windows application in wine. The app can only see COM ports 1-4.

My system has the following usb-serial device:

```
# lsmod | grep cp210x
cp210x                 36864  0

# ls /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 188, 0 Feb 14 00:42 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

How can I present this as COM1 to wine applications?

Comment: In older versions of Wine, edit the configuration file and use `/dev/ttyUSB0` as name for the serial device. But newer Wine versions use the registry, and I've no idea where it is in the registry, and there doesn't seem to be [documentation](https://wiki.winehq.org/Useful_Registry_Keys) for it... ask on the Wine mailing list? (Why do people keep replacing working configuration files with stupid solutions?)

Comment: a quick and dirty way would be to do a bind mount eg. `mount -B /dev/ttyUSB0 /dev/ttyS0`. With mount namespaces / `unshare -Urm`, you can limit this to a process and its descendants .Btw, it would be a better idea to add some udev rules to change the owner of that device; make it owned by a special group like `gadget-user` or similar, and add yourself to it).

Comment: For newer versions of WINE (>= 2.8) the symlinks are reset every times you try to use the port. The [currently] top answer on this question addresses the issue:

https://superuser.com/questions/619528/converting-the-dev-ttyusb-to-com-port-to-use-it-with-wine-in-linux

The relevant section of the WINE user guide:

https://wiki.winehq.org/index.php?title=Wine_User%27s_Guide&oldid=2519#Serial_and_Parallel_Ports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I solved this:

```
cd ~/.wine/dosdevices/
ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 com5
```

**That's all it required.** My Windows app now gave me an option to use COM 5, and it worked right away.

In my research on this I did read that some people need to add a Wine registry key. I did not have to do this.

This is the common option that works with most applications:

```
[Hardware\\Devicemap\\Serialcomm] 1231984861
"Serial0"="COM1"
```

Here are the resources I used for my solution:

Set up the serial port in Wine · One Transistor
https://www.onetransistor.eu/2015/12/wine-serial-port-linux.html

wine - Symbolic Link Between USB and COM Port - Ask Ubuntu
https://askubuntu.com/questions/685985/symbolic-link-between-usb-and-com-port

Converting the /dev/ttyUSB to com port to use it with Wine in Linux - Super User
https://superuser.com/questions/619528/converting-the-dev-ttyusb-to-com-port-to-use-it-with-wine-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

In my research you need to add a string entry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wine\Ports` with a key of `COM1` and a value of `/dev/ttyUSB0` (or `/dev/ttyACM0` if it is the case) to access the USB port from wine.

This is saved in `.wine/system.reg` as

```
[Software\\Wine\\Ports] 1625478112
"COM1"="/dev/ttyACM0"
```